# How do I do 2 unique LEFT JOINs on the same table cell?

Tags: mysql, select, left-join, unique

In mysql I'd like to do 2 unique LEFT JOINs on the same table cell.

I have two tables.

One table lists individual clients and has a clientNoteID and staffNoteID entry for each client.  clientNoteID and staffNoteID are both integer references of a unique noteID for the note store in the notesTable.

**clientsTable:**

```
clientID | clientName | clientNoteID | staffNoteID
```

**notesTable:**

```
noteID | note
```

I'd like to be able to select out of the notesTable both the note referenced by the clientNoteID and the note referenced by the staffNoteID.

I don't see any way to alias a left join like:

```
SELECT FROM clientsTable clientsTable.clientID, clientsTable.clientName, clientsTable.clientNoteID, clientsTable.stylistNoteID
LEFT JOIN notes on clientTable.clientNotesID = notes.noteID
LEFT JOIN notes on clientTable.staffNoteID = notes.noteID as staffNote
```

(not that i think that really makes too much sense)

So, how could I query so that I can print out at the end:

```
clientName | clientNote | staffNote
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you join a table the alas must be immediately after the table name, not after the join condition. Try this instead:

```
SELECT clientsTable.clientName, n1.note AS clientNote, n2.note AS staffNote
FROM clientsTable 
LEFT JOIN notes AS n1 ON clientTable.clientNotesID = n1.noteID
LEFT JOIN notes AS n2 ON clientTable.staffNoteID = n2.noteID
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to alias the tables themselves

```
SELECT FROM clientsTable clientsTable.clientID, clientsTable.clientName, clientsTable.clientNoteID, clientsTable.stylistNoteID
LEFT JOIN notes a on clientTable.clientNotesID = a.noteID
LEFT JOIN notes b on clientTable.staffNoteID = b.noteID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CT.clientName, N1.note AS clientNote, N2.note AS staffNote
FROM clientsTable CT
LEFT JOIN notes N1 on CT.clientNotesID = N1.noteID
LEFT JOIN notes N2 on CT.staffNoteID = N2.noteID
```